# Code style showing "line is longer than allowed by code style (> 100 symbols)"

Tags: macos, android-studio, coding-style

I want to use android studio on Mac as a code editor . but when I edit C/C++ Code , always prompt dialog like : line is longer than allowed by code style(> 100 symbols) . See screen shot below :

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

[Picture uncheck the warinig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGz3S.png) : line is longer than allowed by code style(> 100 symbols)